# Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column - self-join

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to have a custom name for my foreign key. how can I do ?
I'm using below code but it get me error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column
>   'parent_section_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table
>   `sections` add constraint `sections_parent_section_id   _foreign`
>   foreign key (`parent_section_id`) references `sections` (`id`) on
>   delete cascade)

what I want :

`id` - `title` - `parent_section_id`

`parent_section_id` reference to current id table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->foreign('parent_section_id')->references('id')->on('sections')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sections', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_section_id')->unsigned();

        $table->string('title');
        $table->foreign('parent_section_id')
              ->references('id')->on('sections')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```